# Issue with installing rusti (Rust interactive shell)

Tags: rust

I am trying to install Rusti (the Rust programming language interactive shell) from https://github.com/murarth/rusti

But after this command, (as suggested in the GitHub page)

```
rustup run nightly-2016-08-01 cargo install --git https://github.com/murarth/rusti
```

I get this message

> error: aborting due to previous error  error: failed to compile `rusti
>   v0.0.1 (https://github.com/murarth/rusti#9a1eff33)`, intermediate
>   artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install.DeH3oix9x8l3`
>
> Caused by:   Could not compile `rusti`.

Any help would be appreciated, I am on Ubuntu 16.04.